# how do i host a nodejs site on raspberry pi and access it via pc/mobile

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I recently built a home automation system based on Nodejs , where in raspberry pi acts as server and recives data from arduino.However i want to access the webpage outside the rasp. with a ip (eg:192.168.3.4)

Comment: What is your question, what don't you understand and what did you try so far? Could you provide more elements?

Comment: You should already be able to access the raspberry pi from your home network.  If you want to access it from the general internet, then you will have to set up port forwarding from your home router/firewall so that requests coming in to your home IP address on port 80 will be forwarded to the raspberry pi.  In that case, you would make the request to whatever IP address your home router has (not to the private IP address that the raspberry Pi has).

Comment: yeah,exactly this worked for me..!